# How to set a timer for MediaPlayer in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing a phone finder application, and i would like to implement the remote ringing function... I already write a code for MediaPlayer, but when I tested it, the alarm is ringing non-stop (maybe the time for the alarm song is too long but i wanna make it rings for a particular period only)... I hope to set a timer for the alarm ringing like let say ringing for 10 seconds, but no idea on how to achieve it... Need help from you guys... thanks...

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(RingerActivity.this, R.raw.alarm);
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         }
    mp.start();

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Runnable and a Handler to stop the MediaPlayer after 10 seconds.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable stopPlaybackRun = new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }    
};
h.postDelayed(stopPlaybackRun, 10 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Android**

> media player in timer

```
MediaPlayer buzzer; //Outside the method
public void BuzzerSound(){
buzzer=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.buzzer_sound);
Thread timer= new Thread(){
    public void run(){
     try{
         buzzer.start();
         buzzer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
                }
            });
        }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
    };
    timer.start(); }
```